# Select from multiple tables in sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm struggling in how to select from two tables using the Sequelize.

Actually I'm trying to do it:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users, clients WHERE user.id = clients.user_id
```

I have no idea how to user two tables as I described, the only thing I did that got some results were:

```js
const clients = await Client.findAll({
    attributes: ["user_id"],
});

const users = [];
for (const client of clients) {
    let user = await User.findAll({
        where: {
            id: {
                [Op.eq]: client.user_id
            }
        }
    });
    users.push(user);
}
```

Which return me something:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "Velda",
            "middle_name": "Zboncak",
            "last_name": "Kris",
            "email": "vkris10@hotmail.com",
            "created_at": "2020-02-07T20:09:29.484Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-07T20:09:29.484Z"
        }
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Model and Assossiation

First of all, you need to create the correct [associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#defining-the-sequelize-associations) in the model of your table. In this case for the User and the Client, it's supposed to be an `Client.belongsTo(...)`

Take a look at **User** model:

```js
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
class User extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
            middle_name: DataTypes.STRING,
            last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
            email: DataTypes.STRING
        }, { sequelize });
    }
}
module.exports = User;
```

Take a look at **Client** model:

```js
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

class Client extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER // The foreign key
        }, { sequelize });
    }

    static associate(models) {
        Client.belongsTo(models.User, {
            foreignKey: "id", // Column name of associated table
            as: "user" // Alias for the table
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Client;
```

When associating tables you need to have in mind those values inside the `associate` method, being the `foreignKey: "id"` the column name inside the **`models.ModelName`**, which will be used to make the joins, and the `as: "user"` which are used as an alias for the table like `SELECT t.column1 FROM table AS t;`

## Controller

Okay, now you have set your models, you need to set your controller, where the magic happens. As you said you want to fetch results using:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users, clients WHERE user.id = clients.user_id
```

But to achieve the same result you can follow the [sql join method](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to fetch the results from db, so it will be something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    "user"."first_name", "user"."middle_name", "user"."last_name", "user"."email"
FROM "clients" AS "client"
LEFT JOIN "users" AS "user"
ON "client"."id" = "user"."id";
```

Knowing that we can talk about [including tables](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#eager-loading-example) in sequelize, which is the same as [associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#defining-the-sequelize-associations)

```
const Client = require("./path/to/models/Client");
module.exports = {
    async fetchAll(req, res) {
        const results = await Client.findAll({
            limit: 25,
            include: [
                {
                    association: "user",
                    attributes: ["first_name", "middle_name", "last_name", "email"]
                }
            ]
        });
        return res.json(results);
    },
};
```

Now lets talk about what is going on in the code:

- The `Model.findAll({})` will fetch all the result inside the specified table, in this case `clients` table.
- The `limit: 25` will limit your results in only 25 rows, you are free to remove or edit as you need.
- The `include: []`, it will do the joins through the tables you specify, as you need only the `users` table, we are going to use only one object, so the `assossiation: "user"` will make this connection between tables, you must use the same alias you set inside the model. And at least the `attributes: ["columns"]` is where you set all the fields you want to fetch.

And that's it, you make you request, and the result of this will be exactly the same join as I mentioned. And the results will be:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "user": {
            "first_name": "John",
            "middle_name": "Ironsight",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@example.com"
        }
    }, {...}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use **where** in **include**. Find the document at [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html#eager-loading)

```
let user_id = client.user_id;
users = await User.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Client,
            as: 'client',
            where: {
                user_id: user_id
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: It would work in a very particular case, considering you need everytime a new `client.user_id` a for loop would not be great. I think a sql `JOIN` method will give him the results he need.